# dynamic sql generation design

Tags: java, jdbc

Good Afternoon,

We are bulding a web application and as part of it building a search functionality, have a design question on "Search Functionality"

The field names on the UI vs DB are different .i.e. a field on the UI called as "Number" the same is called Text10 in the DB. following are the two issues

1. How to generate a SQL as user gives the UI field names, we have a table in the DB where we r maintaining configuration(UI name to DB Name)?
2. User selects the columns which he wants to search, say for example there fields are selected "Number, Description, Price" and once the sql is generated, how to know what data corresponds to what column? Do we have to maintain an index capturing position or a bean?
   what is the better way to gather the data based on the resultset?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A solution that promotes commonality between UI and database column names would be nice but probably not feasible.

Some sort of mapping table that captures the following will work:

- META-DB-TABLE-NAME
- META-DB-COLUMN-NAME
- META-UI-COLUMN-NAME

Personally I would prefer to keep this mapping meta-data as close to the database as possible.

User-defined meta data is nicely described here from an Oracle perspective:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb_repos_meta.htm

Do some research on this and keep us informed with what you find. Very interesting question!

Answer (score 0):

In such a dynamic SQL scenario, query builders like [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org) really shine. See for example the jOOQ manual section about [dynamic SQL](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dynamic-sql/).

In your specific case, assuming you're using generated code in jOOQ ([which isn't a must, but certainly recommended](https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-use-jooq-with-code-generation/)), you'll be maintaining some sort of lookup between UI fields and SQL fields, such as:

```java
Map<UIField, Field<?>> lookup = ...
lookup.put(UI.NUMBER, TABLE.NUMBER);
lookup.put(UI.DESCRIPTION, TABLE.DESCRIPTION);
lookup.put(UI.PRICE, TABLE.PRICE);
```

You can then construct your query dynamically according to user needs:

```java
List<UIField> userRequestedFields = ...
List<Field<?>> queryFields = userRequestedFields
    .stream()
    .map(lookup::get)
    .toList();
```

And then:

```java
ctx.select(queryFields)
   .from(TABLE)
   .where(...)
   .fetch();
```

There are other query builders, even JPA has the criteria API for these purposes. You could also roll your own, though you'll be re-inventing a lot of wheels.

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ.